# Formula to Sum the values of a column based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

i need to create a formula to sum the values of a column based on two different criteria's, but here's a trick to it that i cant figure out. This is an example of the table

[image]

Here, I have the sum of al "Valor1" which is 18. But, i need that filter to be dynamic so it shows me the sum of all "Material" filter, for example, if i only filter "Mat1" i should get 10, i know i can do that with subtotal(109), but that only works if i have that same row filter, i need to have some sort of resume of all values on Material even if not all cells are visible, this is an example of what i need

[image]

As you can see, i only have one row of Mat1 but i get all values related to that visible value, i need to be able to filter multiple Materials and get the sum of all of them

Edit -------------
This is my database

[image: Database]

Comment: May be a pivot table can help you?

Comment: I need to be a formula since the sheet that i showed is the format that is required

Comment: Would it not be better to mention the values you want to filter on as criteria to the sum, that way your formula would be a lot easier to make and doesn't need to be volatile.

Comment: The problem is that the values on material change every time you run a macro, i was thinking of putting all unique values on another sheet and make a reference to it, but i was still looking for a way to use a formula directly

Comment: I have a solution, it's under developing.

Comment: If you have a macro running, it's best to get it solved using VBA. Much better than using a volatile formula solution

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how they could be combined eloquently, but here's what I came up with.

For your first question, in regards to filtering the sum by Material and Type together, try SumIfs. Before your result cell, establish two variable cells; one for Mat1/Mat2, and the other for Valor1/2/3 etc.

As far as the cell reference, I've found it to be easier to reference tables than specific ranges (and excel will update the range size as the table increases or decreases depending on your data).

So for this let's make your overall range (C9:E21) a table [with headers].
Then, the cell references will be "Table1[Material]", "Table1[Type]", and "Table1[Semana]"

For your double criteria sum try this:
`=SUMIFS(Table1[Semana],Table1[Material],G4,Table1[Type],H4)`

If you want to just filter for Material then try: `=SUMIF(Table1[Material],G5,Table1[Semana])`

And if you want to filter for just Type then try:
`=SUMIF(Table1[Type],H6,Table1[Semana])`

[image: Here is a picture outlining how I organized the data]

Keep in mind, cells G4,G5,H4, and H6 are all dropdown menus, and Column K:K is only there to show the formulas used in the previous column.

If I haven't been clear on anything, or if you have any questions, feel free to ask. I'm no expert though, so I make no promises, lol.

Answer (score 0):

The main challenge in this task is to interact with AutoFilter from a worksheet formula. It's resolved by the user-defined function `GetFilters`.

The developed solution (Excel 365, 2019) consists of the user-defined function `GetFilters` and the formula.
[image]

I created the test dataset `Mat1-Mat5`.

```
Public Function GetFilters(Ref As Range) As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, av As Variant, cnt As Integer
  With Ref.WorkSheet.AutoFilter.Filters(Ref.Column - Ref.Worksheet.AutoFilter.Range.Column + 1)
    On Error GoTo NoFilterHndlr
    cnt = .Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case cnt
      Case 1:
        GetFilters = Array(Mid$(.Criteria1, 2))
      Case 2:
        GetFilters = Array(Mid$(.Criteria1, 2), Mid$(.Criteria2, 2))
      Case Else:
        ReDim arr(cnt - 1)
        For i = 1 To cnt
          arr(i - 1) = Mid$(.Criteria1(i), 2)
        Next
        GetFilters = arr
    End Select
  End With
  Exit Function
NoFilterCode:
  On Error GoTo 0
  av = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(Ref)
  cnt = UBound(av, 1) - 1
  ReDim arr(cnt)
  For i = 0 To cnt
    arr(i) = av(i + 1, 1)
  Next
  GetFilters = arr
  Exit Function
NoFilterHndlr:
  Resume NoFilterCode
End Function
```

The formula is:

```
[F1:F6]=SUM(SUMIFS($C$9:$C$38,$B$9:$B$38,E1,$A$9:$A$38,getfilters($A$9:$A$38)))
```

The formula for your range is:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($E$10:$E$21;$D$10:$D$21;D2;$C$10:$C$21;getfilters($C$10:$C$21)))
```

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: Hi, so sorry for the delay, I modified my ranges as I needed but the formula with the function does not work.

This is my modified formula `=SUM(SUMIFS($N$19:$N$54,$L$19:$L$54,L5,$J$19:$J$54,getfilters($J$19:$J$54)))`

The results are 0

Comment: You can modify the function and the formula. I can help if you provide the sample of your new data.

Comment: Hii, I modified the question and added the database at the end because it didn't let me add pictures as comments, I used the formula i mentioned

Comment: The problem is how you applied the autofilter. As I can see on your picture, you applied the autofilter to columns starting from A and may be up to the last column. It's not correct, but I modified the third line of the function code to allow the function work regardless of the number of columns and the start column. The argument of the function should refer the column you are interested in. Also I provided the formula exactly for your data range as you initially depicted and mentioned.

Comment: Your formula on the last picture is correct. You only need to modify the third line of the function code "With Ref...."

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: Hi, formula works fine with one material filter, if i filter two it looks like the last value gets freezed, and if I put three or more I get 0 again

Comment: It's not interesting to help you.

Comment: sorry for that, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a "helper" column you could add a `SUBTOTAL` formula in column `F` and use that in your `SUMIF` formula.

So `F10` dragged down would be `=SUBTOTAL(109,E10)` and your `E2:E7` would be `=SUMIF(D10:D21,D2,F10:F21)`

[image]

And when filtered (note the reference to F16 is returning 0 now)
[image]

Comment: Your solution looks good, but I observe a defect here. At the second picture, row 21 is not filtered out. My Excel 365 behaves the same. Of cause, it affects calculation, and the defect itself looks strange.

Comment: The autofilter on a range without SUBTOTAL column works well. To fix the issue, it necessary to add the `Total` row.